# How to convert JSON data in Android?

Tags: android, json

I am new to JSON and I am trying to convert string to JSON object, I have got a string from this link
http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/ 
I am trying to convert this data into Json Object, but while converting data into a json Object i am getting an error.

[Error given by compiler that can't convert string to json object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZ4I7.png).

I got data in a String , but now I don't know how to convert this data into an object, please help me.

Comment: please post your code.

Comment: Use Jackson ModelMapper -> http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/jackson-integration/

Comment: May be this i you are looking for :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605913/how-to-parse-json-in-android

Comment: Take a look at the different constructors for creating JSONObjects: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the Google's [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or the android built-in `org.json.JSONObject`.

Example using `Gson`:

```
JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
```

Example using `org.json.JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

Also if you consume API calls using the popular [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit) library, it can automatically do the conversion.

Comment: i have converted this data to json Object

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/google/gson) library, it is one of the best and easy to use.

Then you just generate a POJO from your json just pasting your json  [here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
(Remember to pock Gson when you generate the code)

EDIT: I also noticed that your source JSON is not well formed

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html

Specifically notice how the constructor for a JSONObject can take different arguments. Make sure you are passing in the right arguments in the right circumstances based on how your string is formatted.

Answer (score 0):

The response being returned is a JSONObject . To convert JSON string to json object ,use

```
JSONObject obj=null;
try{
obj=new JSONObject(YOUR_STRING);
}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

After this you have retrieve JSONArray at each key by using

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("number");
```